# cant type password when using passwd command

Tags: password, passwd

when i use the passwd command i get this output:

```
Changing password for root
Enter the new password (minimum of 5 characters)
Please use a combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers.
Bad password: too short.  
Warning: weak password (enter it again to use it anyway).
passwd: password changed.
```

except i didnt type anything but the passwd command, didnt press enter except for running the command didnt fill in my password i didnt do anything, i have tried to reinstall shadow but that didnt work i have tried setting the password from the installation media but i dont think thats even possible

Comment: Did you do a copy and paste into the terminal? Sometimes copy and paste can trigger an enter key press.

Comment: no i did not copy paste